# Figuring out if points are the same in FME

Tags: spatial-analyst, fme-form

So I am working on a project using spatial point data in FME.  Both files contain 500 points and the hope is they are all the same.  To figure out if any are different I was thinking of using **PointOnPointOverlayer** tool instead of a **spatial realtor**.

What are your thoughts guys on this or is their a better way.  Just for heads up both files contain same information but from different sources so id and other useful information would not be the same to use a simple feature merger and then take unmerged ones as the different ones.

The goal is to figure out what records are not in the other data set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try the [ChangeDetector](https://www.safe.com/transformers/change-detector/) with no attributes -- so you'd set it up to only compare geometries.  Just have it compare no attributes.

Takes a wee bit of concentration to figure out what all the ports do, but if you check the documentation it should be clear enough.

You could accomplish the same result with a [PointOnPointOverlayer](https://www.safe.com/transformers/point-on-point-overlayer/) but it would be more work to post-process the results to figure out who'd be added or deleted. You'd need to set attributes up prior to going in and then examine what comes out once the attributes of matching points are merged.  So it could be done but it would be harder. Note -- if you wanted to handle non-exact matches, then you'd have to go this way as ChangeDetector demands exact location matching, whereas point on point has a tolerance.

PS: Feel free to post over on the [new FME community](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/index.html) as others there may have additional insight.